# Why is xcrun returning 'missing Info.plist'?

Tags: macos, xcrun, tauri

I am trying to upload a mac app to the Apple store but `xcrun altool` gives the following error:

```
Error: ...The package is missing an Info.plist or the CFBundlePackageType is not ‘APPL’ or ‘FMWK’...
```

The app bundle contains `Info.plist` with the `CFBundlePackageType` set to `APPL` (see below). The app is created by Tauri and signed with my Apple distribution certificate.

How do I fix this and upload my app?

Command:

```
xcrun altool --upload-app --file "my-app.app" --type macos -u "my-id" -p "my-password"
```

Error:

```
2023-01-17 18:14:51.476 *** Error: Error uploading 'my-app.app'.
2023-01-17 18:14:51.476 *** Error: Could not determine the package’s bundle ID. The package is missing an Info.plist or the CFBundlePackageType is not ‘APPL’ or ‘FMWK’. Unable to validate your application. (-21017)
 {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Could not determine the package\U2019s bundle ID. The package is missing an Info.plist or the CFBundlePackageType is not \U2018APPL\U2019 or \U2018FMWK\U2019.";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Unable to validate your application.";
}
```

my-app.app/Contents/Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>My App</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>My App</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>my.site.my-app</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>My App</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>20230117.230842</string>
    <key>CSResourcesFileMapped</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string>public.app-category.developer-tools</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.13</string>
    <key>LSRequiresCarbon</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright 2023</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key></key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out why you got this error?

Comment: It took me weeks to tease out the answer but I did. Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, you **can not** directly upload an app bundle (my-app.app) to the app store. You have a number of things you need to do but you will finally need to create a signed product package (my-app.pkg).

Steps:

```
Configure tauri.conf.json (if using Tauri)
Set a Version Number
Create the App Bundle
Create entitlements.plist
Add Provisioning Profile
Sign the App Bundle
Create Signed Package
Upload
```

See my full write-up on deploying an app to the app store [here](https://thinkgo.io/post/2023/02/publish_tauri_to_apples_app_store/). This is focused on deploying a Tauri app but the basics apply to uploading any non-Xcode Mac app to the app store.